# Modalize does not override react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Each time the user taps on a specific element I want to appear a modalize that describes everything of what the user tapped, I am using [Modalize](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize) and tried to use portalize but I can't make the modalize appear first of tapbar.

[image: My current result is this:]

My App.js code where the navigation is.

```js
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext";
import { setNavigator } from "./src/navigationRef";
import AccountScreen from "./src/screens/AccountScreen";
import Exp from "./src/screens/Exp";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/LoggedIn/HomeScreen";
import Onboarding from "./src/screens/NotLogged/Onboarding";
import SigninScreen from "./src/screens/NotLogged/SigninScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./src/screens/NotLogged/SignupScreen";
import ResolveAuthScreen from "./src/screens/ResolveAuthScreen";
import TrackCreateScreen from "./src/screens/TrackCreateScreen";
import TrackDetailScreen from "./src/screens/TrackDetailScreen";
import TrackListScreen from "./src/screens/TrackListScreen";

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  ResolveAuth: ResolveAuthScreen,
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Onboarding: Onboarding,
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen,
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    trackListFlow: createStackNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      TrackList: TrackListScreen,
      TrackDetail: TrackDetailScreen,
    }),
    CreateTrack: TrackCreateScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen,
    Exp: Exp,
  }),
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App
        ref={(navigator) => {
          setNavigator(navigator);
        }}
      />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is, Modalize doesn't use react-native `Modal` which has separate activity render on top of everything but you can still use react-native `Modal` by adding this property to your modalize.

- **withReactModal**

If you wanted to render your modal on top of everything you must your [Portal](https://github.com/burstware/react-native-portal)  or [Portalize](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-portalize) which is the cloned version of the first one

You should wrap your app with `Portal.Host` like this,

```
<AuthProvider>
    <Portal.Host>
        <App
           ref={(navigator) => {
           setNavigator(navigator);
          }}
        />
    </<Portal.Host>
</AuthProvider>
```

And then warp your modalize component with a portal like this.

```
const AppModalize = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Portal>
      <Modalize
        {...props}
        ref={ref}
      >
        {props.children}
      </Modalize>
    </Portal>
  )
})
export default AppModalize
```

Now use this component to render your modalize.

Comment: When using `withReactModal`, however, the modal cannot be dismissed by swiping down on Android... I've tried wrapping the whole root `NavigationContainer` with `<Host>` from portalize, but when I try to open a `<Modalize>` instance which is wrapped with `<Portal>`, I get this error: "TapGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView. Otherwise the gestures will not be recognized."

Comment: I solved my problem by wrapping my `<NavigationContainer>` with `<Host>` and `<Host>` with `<GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1}}>`